# how to go from net module to ws module

Tags: node.js

here is my current code

```
'use strict';
var _       = require('underscore'),
    util    = require('util'),
    events  = require('events'),
    net     = require('net'),
    colors  = require('colors');

// Chatango Socket connection handler, for both Rooms and PM
// Available events: onconnect, data, error, timeout, close, write ( Note: exceptions must be handled! )

function Socket(host, port)
{
    this._host = host;
    this._port = port || 443;
    this._socket = new net.Socket();

    this._pingTask = false;

    this._connected = false;

    this._firstCommand = true;
    this._writeLock = false;
    this._writeBuffer = [];
    this._buffer = '';

    this.connect();
}

util.inherits(Socket, events.EventEmitter);

Socket.prototype.connect = function()
{
    if(this._socket._connecting) return;

    var self = this;

    if(this._socket.destroyed){
        var reconnecting = true;
        console.log('[SOCKET] reconnecting to '+this._host+':'+this._port);
    }else{
        var reconnecting = false;
        console.log('[SOCKET] connecting to '+this._host+':'+this._port);
    }

    this._writeLock = true;

    if(this._socket._events.connect){
        this._socket.connect(this._port, this._host);
    }else{
        this._socket.connect(this._port, this._host, function() {
            self._connected = true;
            self._writeLock = false;

            self._pingTask = setInterval(function() {
                if(self._connected) {
                    self.write(['']);
                }
            }, 30000);

            self.emit('onconnect');
        });
    }

    if(reconnecting) return;

    this._socket.on('data', function(data) {

        var buffer = data.toString('utf8');

        if(buffer.substr(-1) !== '\x00')
        {
            self._buffer += buffer;
        }
        else
        {
            if(self._buffer != '')
            {
                buffer = self._buffer + buffer;
                self._buffer = '';
            }
            var messages = buffer.split('\x00');

            _.each(messages, function(message){

                message = message.replace(/(\r|\n)/g, '');

                if(message !== '')
                    self.emit('data', message);

            });
        }

    });

    this._socket.on('error', function(exception) {
        self.emit('error', exception);
    });

    this._socket.on('timeout', function(exception) {
        self.emit('timeout', exception);
    });

    this._socket.on('close', function() {
        self._connected = false;
        self._writeBuffer = [];
        self._writeLock = false;
        self._buffer = '';
        self._firstCommand = true;
        clearInterval(self._pingTask);
        self.emit('close');
    });

}

Socket.prototype.disconnect = function(){
    this._socket.destroy();
}

Socket.prototype.setWriteLock = function(bool) {
    this._writeLock = _.isBoolean(bool) && bool;
}

Socket.prototype.write = function(data) {

    if(this._connected)
    {
        if(this._firstCommand)
        {
            var terminator = '\x00';
            this._firstCommand = false;
        }
        else
            var terminator = '\r\n\x00';

        if(this._writeLock) 
            this._writeBuffer.push(data);
        else
        {
            _.each(this._writeBuffer, function(value){
                this.write(value);
            }.bind(this));

            if(data)
                this.emit('write', data.join(':'));
            this._socket.write(data.join(':') + terminator);
        }
    }
}

exports.Instance = Socket;
```

as you can see i am using the net module

i want to change to the ws module and do this using websockets https://github.com/einaros/ws

i've read all kinds of examples but none of them give me what i want

the lib im using is 
https://github.com/MakuraYami/derplib

Comment: You can change with the (easy) socket.io module and chosing to use ws transport http://socket.io/

Comment: this is strictly for a nodejs client to connect to a chat websockets NO BROWSER STUFF OR HTML STUFF if socket.io can do that then show me how